# jquery click prevent going to top of page

Tags: jquery

I have a number of images on my page. Some are at the bottom of the page which requires scrolling. What I am finding is that when I click on the image which in turn turns into a video  it makes me to go the top of the page.

Here is the code I  have:

```
$('#videoconner').click(function () {
     $(this).replaceWith('<iframe width="280" height="164" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6kR2n4344UCAU?autoplay=1&cc_load_policy=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
});
```

I added :

```
e.preventDefault();
```

but that did not help.

Is there anyway to prevent from going to the top of the page?

Comment: While doing `e.preventDefault();`, did you have `e` in function brakets? `function(e){e.preventDefault()}`

Answer (score 3):

Add an `e` (for the event parameter) to your click function.

```
$('#videoconner').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).replaceWith('<iframe width="280" height="164" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6kR2n4344UCAU?autoplay=1&cc_load_policy=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to return false; to make it stop the click event from doing the default action & continuing to bubble up the DOM:

```
$('#videoconner').click(function () {
  $(this).replaceWith('<iframe width="280" height="164" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6kR2n4344UCAU?autoplay=1&cc_load_policy=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
  return false;
});
```

Read this for more info on the subject: [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

**Note:** Returning false only calls e.stopPropagation if using jQuery, as this question does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `preventDefault` like this (*add `e` in callback function parameter*)

```
$('#videoconner').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).replaceWith('<iframe width="280" height="164" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6kR2n4344UCAU?autoplay=1&cc_load_policy=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
});
```